# YouTube OAuth Auth

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use YouTube's Data v3 API to search for videos in react. So I use OAuth to sign-in a user (using next-auth) and then I get an accessToken from the Session which I use as authorization to the YouTube's Data GET request. But the problem is when I try to send a GET request, I get a 403 forbidden error. I feel like I am messing up with the scopes. This is how I write the scopes in the code:

```
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            // Specify the scopes you need as an array of strings
            scope: [
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
            ]
        }),
```

Is this how I write the scopes? Or is the way I am accessing the YouTube API wrong? Thanks a lot!